# Will this fstab file work?

Tags: mount, fstab

I am editing some partitions, and I'm not sure about how to correctly modify my `fstab`.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/md3p1 /home ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/md3p2 /data/rtorrent ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/md3p3 /data/plex ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/md3p4 /data/software ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Will this work? I'm a bit cautious because its a remote server, so I cannot do recovery if it fails to boot

The partitions have all been successfully mounted  by `mount /dev/md3p1 /home` and so forth.

Besides editing the file, do I need to do anything else when updating `/etc/fstab`>

Trying Micheal's solution, I made my fstab this way:

```
/proc    /proc      nonproc       defaults     errors=remount-ro  1
/dev/md/0      /swap     swap    errors=noremount-rw      1 
/dev/md/1 /boot    /    defaults boot   errors=remount-rw      1
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults  nodep errors=noremount-ro 1
/dev/md3p1 /home ext4 defaults  nodep errors=noremount-ro 1  
/dev/md3p2 /data/rtorrent ext4 defaults  nodep errors=noremount-ro 1
/dev/md3p3 /data/plex ext4 defaults  nodep errors=noremount-ro 1
/dev/md3p4 /data/software ext4 defaults  nodep errors=noremount-ro 1
```

with this fstab `mount -a` output is

```
[mntent]: line 1 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 3 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 4 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 5 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 6 in /etc/fstab is bad; rest of file ignored
```

output of`ls /dev | grep md` is

```
md0
md1
md2
md3
md3p1
md3p2
md3p3
md3p4
```

Comment: What have you changed compaired to original fstab? E.g. did you touch /etc/mdadm.conf?

Comment: The original fstab had this line '/dev/md/3 /home ext4 defaults 0 0'.
I originally tried to setup LVM on md3 but ended up making the partitions using gparted. 
At the beginning i only had a md3 in /dev , not any md3px

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer, or did you figure out how to do this? Maybe you could post your own answer to help others if so